# Progress Application Server invalid webapp in wsdl

Tags: tomcat, wsdl, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I'm creating a new web service adapter in Progress 11.3 OpenEdger Server with this steps:

1) Stop Tomcat

2) Copy the **"/PROGRESS_DIR/servlets/wsa"** directory to **"/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/"** directory

3) Rename "/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/**wsa**" directory to "/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/**bsp**" directory

4) Start Tomcat, this action creates the **"wsa1"** directory in "/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/**bsp**" directory. The **wsa1** has two files:

```
Default.prop
DeployedServices.ds
```

5) Create the web service adapter on the Progress Application Server Console, with this parameters:

```
name: bsp
URL: http://IP_SERVER:8080/bsp/wsa1
Location: local
```

6) The **bsp** adapter is actived, its color is green in the Progress Application Server Console

7) Copy the **Service.wsm** file to **"/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/bsp/wsa1/"** directory. This file has the "http://IP_SERVER:8080/bsp/wsa1" value in "SoapEndpointURL" tag.

```
<SoapEndpointURL>http://IP_SERVER:8080/bsp/wsa1</SoapEndpointURL>
```

8) Deploy the **Service** on **bsp** adapter with this information

```
WMS File: /TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/bsp/wsa1/Service.wsm
```

**¡NOW, THE ERROR!**

When I executed the step 8, this action creates the **Service.wsdl** file in the **"/TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/bsp/wsa1/"** directory, that is correct!, however this file contents the **BAD** URL in the **soap:address** tag.

```
<soap:address location="http://IP_SERVER:8080/wsa/wsa1"/>
```

/wsa/? Why? Ummm?

The next is the correct!

```
<soap:address location="http://IP_SERVER:8080/bsp/wsa1"/>
```

Yes! **/bsp/** and not **/wsa/**.

Additional Information:

```
Linux Red Hat 6
Progress 11.3
Tomcat 5.5.20
```

Answer (score 0):

The SoapEndpointURL has a value *inside* the .wsm file. Adjust this *before* deploying the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "ubroker.properties" file for the corresponding WSA - that's where the "location url" is stored.

If you find it, then shut down TomCat and the adminserver, change the URL, and start them up again. You may also need to *undeploy* and *deploy* the webservice itself for the change to fully "take."

Comment: Why? I need to change this URL for each new web server adapter? This is tedious!

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the WSA address - this is how you'd do it. Each WSA has it's own address, which is stored in the ubroker.properties file. Each WSA can host multiple _services_, so there's no need to change the WSA address if all you're doing is adding another service to a WSA.